# Ubuntu 18.04+ dock running out of space

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In Unity if there are lots of things pinned to the dock, the dock becomes "spongy": hovering over the bottom of the dock automatically expands that portion of the dock.

Can the Ubuntu Dock in 18.04+ behave the same way?

The issue I am having is that I have 15 or so items pinned to the dock and the last few ones cannot be accessed because the dock has no more visible room. I could resize the icons, but they become too small if I want to fit all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a mouse with a scrollwheel, place the mouse pointer over the launcher and scroll up or down. If you have a laptop, you maybe able to use two-finger scrolling to do the same thing.

[image: Overflowing dock]